# Limit result source recursion

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

I am trying to limit a result source in sharepoint 2013 from returning all subsites with a path.

my query is `{searchTerms}contentclass:STS_Web path:http://site.domain.com/level1`

I would only want is to return sites one level lower.

ie http://site.domain.com/level1/level2_1
http://site.domain.com/level1/level2_2

I do not want it to return subsites with the level2 sites. Is there anything I can add to my query to limit the subsite recursion? thanks